# Microsoft Outlook 2010 Cannot Import PST File

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, outlook, outlook-2010

I am still moving some local accounts to domain accounts and today I am having issues with Outlook 2010.

I have a local username with all the Outlook information in it. So I've exported all the information I wanted to a PST file saved in C:

Then, in the domain username I went to Outlook and tried to import from *File* > *Import* or *Open* and I always get this error:

> **Microsoft Outlook:**
>
> Access Denied to the file. You haven't enough privileges to have gain access to file C:\Emails.pst

I've searched for some solutions and I did try the following ones without any luck:

- Uncheck ***Read file*** from **File Properties** (it wasn't checked at all)
- Run Outlook 2010 as Administrator
- Add permissions to Domain user in File *Properties* > *Security* tab

I did try with **suggested contacts** and some local folders. How could make this work? Any ideas are appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: File permissions and its location... Why is the file in `C:\Emails.pst`, not somewhere like  `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` where it would already have inherited suitable permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Move the file to another location, such as D:\, then try again.

I ever encountered similar issues when loading file from root system drive C:\, moving it to another drive fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

“**Access denied**” error can happen if you have switched from logging on to your computer with a local account to a Microsoft account while the PST file was in use.

**To fix it right-click the PST file,**

**Choose Properties** >> **Security** >> **Edit** >> **choose your Microsoft account**, and **select Full control**.

And Restart Outlook.
This will work.

If Unfortunately, this doesn't work I suggest Import your PST file with the help of any tool i.e. Add Outlook PST tool.